# Let $A, B$ be square matrices. If $A B = A + B$, then $A B = B A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think the following problem is not difficult, but I cannot solve it.

Prove the following fact.

> Let $A, B$ be square matrices.
>   If $A B = A + B$, then $A B = B A$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much.